# Destructuring giving parsing error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand destructuring in ES2015 (ECMAScript 6).

I want a function to work on some variables and reassign the new variables back.

In the example below I have created a function to initialize foo and bar, and another function to change foo and bar.

I have then created three functions that use foo and bar.  Two of them work, and one does not.  I can't seem to figure out why.

Please share any insight to assist my understanding.

Thanks!

```js
function initializeFooBar() {
  let foo = 1,
      bar = 2;
  return {foo, bar};
}
function changeFooBar(f, b) {
  let foo = f*2,
      bar = b*2;
  return {foo, bar};
}
function fooBarWorks() {
  let {foo, bar} = initializeFooBar();
  console.log(foo + bar); // 3
}
function fooBarAlsoWorks() {
  let f = 1,
      b = 2,
      {foo, bar} = changeFooBar(f, b);
  console.log(foo + bar); // 6
}
function fooBarDoesntWork() {
  let {foo, bar} = initializeFooBar();
  {foo, bar} = changeFooBar(foo, bar);  // causes parsing error
  console.log(foo + bar);
}
fooBarWorks(); // writes 3 to console
fooBarAlsoWorks(); // writes 6 to console
fooBarDoesntWork(); // doesn't run due to "parsing error unexpected tolken ="
```

Comment: A `{` at the beginning of a statement is parsed as a block, not an object constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change:

```
{foo, bar} = changeFooBar(foo, bar);
```

to:

```
({foo, bar} = changeFooBar(foo, bar));
```

because `{` in this case is interpreted as a opening of a block of code.

Surrounding the assignment with `()` disambiguates the meaning of `{`.

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The `( .. )` around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a:1, b:2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on
>   the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a:1, b:2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a:1, b:2}`

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda X and @fayazmiraz.  This is very helpful.  Is there any reason other than the need for surrounding ( )s to use [ ] rather than { }?  I noticed both were mentioned in the MDN documentation.